# How to get JSON data from this API?

Tags: java, json, authentication, http-headers, httpurlconnection

I am trying to access data from `http://www.football-data.org` with this API call which returns JSON.

> http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/398/teams

Here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL(jsonurl);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

String authcode = "46cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxec23";
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Auth-Token",authcode);

InputStream instream = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));

while(reader.readLine() != null){
    json_str = reader.readLine();
}
```

I got the api token in mail and the documentation requires the client to use a HTTP header called "X-Auth-Token".

The log shows that json_str is null. I have used the necessary permissions in manifest. Anyone with a solution?

Comment: Have you made that call from your desktop using something like the chrome PostMan plugin? Make that work first, and see what the response looks like.  Also, don't show where you log out json_str, but you overwrite json_str each time through the loop - if the last line of the response is an empty string, then that's what you'll get when you exit the loop.

Comment: It's null because you're reading one line out of two into json_str, and just keep the last one read. Your reading code makes no sense. Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read-char:A-int-int- in a loop until it returns -1, and append the read characters to a StringBuilder. Or just pass the Reader to your JSON parser, and it will read everything for you.